# how do make doxygen generate index-color PNG files

Tags: png, doxygen

For our purposes (LibreOffice), we generate a lot of documentation (more than 10G) so shrinking the output is useful.

At the moment we are setting

```
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = gif
```

in our

```
solenv/inc/doxygen.cfg
```

since that appears to generate index-color GIF files, which are smaller than the PNG files that Doxygen generates.

It wouldbe nice to be able to have Doxygen generate indexed-color PNG files, since that would be even smaller.

Comment: I think the dot program from graphviz does not output indexed format.

Comment: Thanks, I have logged a feature request against GraphViz at http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2502

Comment: And the feature has been implemented already, thanks a lot to the great hackers at GraphWiz!

Comment: I've just pushed a possible solution in doxygen to github (pull request 297), Note that this will only work with newer versions of dot (2.39) and also there are possible problems with the dot generated image (http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2515).